# ASMX webservice giving error - The data at the root level is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx

I am new in web services, not really understand the flow of ws. 
This is my searchOrderWebService.cs .

```
   [WebMethod]
    public int searchOrderID(string orderID)
    {   
    CheckProductTrack checkProductTrack = new CheckProductTrack();
    int Tid = checkProductTrack.getTrackRecord(orderID, 3);

    return Tid;
}



[WebMethod]
public List<ProgressDetails> getOrderIDProgress(int orderID)
{
    return ProgressTrackClass.ProgressTrack.getProgress(orderID).ToList();
}



[WebMethod]
public DataSet getTxDetails(int orderID)
{

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT  tradeit.TSTxDetails.TxID, tradeit.TSTxDetails.ProductID, tradeit.TSTxDetails.ProductName, tradeit.TSTxDetails.Qty, tradeit.TSTxMaster.TxStatus "
                                     + " FROM tradeit.TSTxDetails INNER JOIN tradeit.TSTxMaster ON tradeit.TSTxMaster.TxID=tradeit.TSTxDetails.TxID WHERE tradeit.TSTxDetails.TxID='" + orderID + "' ", con);

    con.Open();
    da.Fill(ds);

    return ds;
}
```

The flow is :

when the user input the OrderId, and Click the button, it will direct the user to webservice, and search for the orderID in trackItem table.

if the orderID present in the trackITem table, then it will display the progress.

IF the orderID not present in trackITem table, it will go to TxDetails table and if present, it will display the progress.

Until now my webservice is working only if the orderID is in table TrackItem,

if it is in other table , it will give this error

```
  Exception Details: System.Xml.XmlException: The data at the root level is 

  invalid. Line 1, position 1.




 Line 638:      [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute
(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrow   sableState.Advanced)]
 Line 639:searchOrderServiceReference.searchOrderIDResponsesearchOrderServiceReference.
 searchOrderWebServiceSoap.
 searchOrderID
 (searchOrderServiceReference.searchOrderIDRequest request) {
 Line 640:            return base.Channel.searchOrderID(request);
  Line 641:        }
```

AND this is my FormCLient , where i accessing the webservice from.

```
 public partial class FormClient : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
  SqlConnection con
  = new SqlConnection
  (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TMXEntities"]
  .ConnectionString);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //RETRIVEING TXID ENTERED BY USER
    string TxID = TextBox1.Text;
    Label1.Text = "Tracking Details For Order No :" + TxID + " ";



    //webservice
    searchOrderServiceReference.searchOrderWebServiceSoapClient client = new searchOrderServiceReference.searchOrderWebServiceSoapClient();
    int trackingID = client.searchOrderID(TxID);



    //IF TX ID IS IN ANY ONE OF THE TABLE, THEN PROCEDD TO GET THE PROGRESS TRACK
    if (trackingID != 0)
    {
        GridView3.DataSource = null;
        GridView3.DataBind();

        Label2.Text = "";

        GridView1.DataSource = client.getOrderIDProgress(trackingID);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = null;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        GridView3.DataSource = client.getTxDetailsStatusItem(trackingID);
        GridView3.DataBind();
     }
    }
   }
```

i am really blurr about serialize , xml, POST GET word. How the proper webservice in asp.net should look like.

Thank you

Comment: I would use fiddler to see what the soap envelope and payload look like. Might give you a better insight into what is invalid.

Comment: it is like this, the orderID will go through searchOrderID( )-- whereby this function will search this ID in table trackITem. if it is not in trackItem, it will proceed to table txDetails n table TradeRequest. My problem is, if the user enter orderID that already in the trackITem, this webservice  will work  nicely n display nicely, but if the order ID is not in trackItem, n need to proceed to other table, it just not returning the ID to next function, getOrderIDProgress()..

Comment: So to understand the issue it is when your logic cascades into the else clause on your client and you call client.GetTxDetailsStatusItem(trackingId) you are never getting any responses?

Comment: yes.. thats wer the problem starts from

Comment: If you run your SQL with Id of 0 what do you return from the query? Since your tracking ID will always be zero.

Comment: it will come out same error, orderID 0 is not in the database, thts y it returning error

Comment: its like FORMcLIENT(user input orderID) --> asmx(search for orderID)--> return to FORMcLIENT(to get the progress)--> asmx(executing getProgress process)--> back to FORMcLIENT(Display the result in gridview). so in between shld i seriealize or do smthing, becoz ws will return result as xml right?

Comment: I dont know you DB schema to help you solve that. You need some other unique criteria to search GetTxDetailsStatusItem with

Comment: You are getting them back as the types you are expecting. I believe its the lack of response that is causing your headaches. I have a feeling if you looked at the requests and responses in Fiddler you would see the invalid data coming up when you response is null.

Comment: oh ok i will take a look with fiddler :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, hi, may we know what is the code of this `client.getTxDetailsStatusItem(trackingID);`? it seems your displayed asmx only contains `public DataSet getTxDetails(int orderID)`

Comment: ooppss sorry actually it is the same mistype

Comment: the DataSet getTxDetails(int orderID), i mistyped here, the coding in my sys is just fine :D so dnt knw wats the problem is

Comment: since like the flow is like from formclient to ws n back to form n back to ws, should i use serializer or smthing becoz maybe the result is in xml and the following function couldnt get it. how this asmx works actually, there are many terms that i m not used with >.<

Comment: Hmm, have you tried instead of returning a DataSet, return a DataTable?

Comment: nah, I think its just my way to troubleshoot, it should still return a dataset however, have you tried debugging if the dataset.Tables[0] has content?